# Uninstalling a program doesn't remove shortcuts from Start menu

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, uninstall, start-menu

This problem started very recently after a system restore.

Each time I uninstall a program, it uninstalls correctly but the shortcuts remain in the Start menu. I can easily delete them by right-clicking on them, but it is an irritant and I was wondering why this is hapenning.

I tried changing the permissions on `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` but it did not help. What else can I try?

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

EDIT: 
This is happening for every application I try to install/uninstall. Audacity, Worldwind, Google Earth, TORCS, Evernote, Mendeley, Google Drive the lot...
I am using the Control Panel -> Remove software utility. (default tool)

And I know for a fact all these have proper installers which do delete all shortcuts.

Comment: What programs are you uninstalling?  Are you using their uninstaller, or the windows "Programs and Features" to uninstall the application.  I'm going to play devils advocate to the answer to see if it is the application(s) or you pc.  But I need to know more first.

Comment: @Angel This is happening for EVERY application I try to install/uninstall. Audacity, Worldwind, Google Earth, TORCS, Evernote, Mendeley, Google Drive

Comment: I did not say I disbelieved you.  I understand how frustrating it can be when there is a problem that just doesn't seem to make sense.  I will hash this out and see what I can come up with.  I appreciate your helping me narrow this down a little bit.  You might try a registry cleaner/repair program, or rolling the pc back using system restore to a point where this was not happening.  As frustrating as that might be.

Comment: @angel I am sorry if I came across as a wee bit frustrated. This is actually a minor worry compared to the fact Nasa Worldwind is broken on Win7. 
And I should apologize for not providing enough info in the first place.
Anyway. I will roll back to a previous version. PLease propose that as a solution, in case it works?

Comment: @Angel This does not seem to be a very widespread problem (although I did find one more question about this) so MS does not have anything in their KB about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt to repair the registry or windows system files through one of the following methods.

1. Use a registry repair application (there are several free and free to try on [CNet](http://download.cnet.com)
2. Use the System Restore in windows to rollback to a previous restore point where the installer and uninstaller for windows was working
3. Use a restoration method from the manufacturer or windows 7 disc to repair system files.  Please backup to secure your system data.

Comment: Reverting to older state solved the problem. I guess an office installation caused this. But I can only speculate.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the programs's uninstall routine to delete shortcuts. If they don't, you just
have to do it manually.

Comment: This is happening for EVERY application I try to install/uninstall. Audacity, Worldwind, Google Earth, TORCS, Evernote, Mendeley, Google Drive. And I know for a fact all these have proper installers which do delete all shortcuts.